# K Means Clustering in R - ignoring row id

Tags: r

I have data frame as follows:

```
X1      X2         X3
3   102.20000   26.07667 
4   115.00000   25.12500
5   36.70000    35.05545
```

Where column X1 denotes unique identifier for a row while X2, X3 are features

I want to perform scaling before performing k means clustering on a data,

```
 mydata <- scale(mydata)


  X1               X2            X3
-11715.6     -12.2200734    -9.7826627
-11714.6       0.5799266    -10.7343294
-11713.6      -77.7200734   -0.8038748
```

I don't want column X1 to scale but want it to remain on data frame. Any way to do it?

Comment: Just subset the dataset and perform the `scale` on columns other than the first column (if I understand your question)  `mydata[,-1] <- scale(mydata[,-1])`

Answer (score 5):

You can tag the unique identifier on to the data frame rows via their `rownames`.

```
rownames(mydata) = mydata$X1
mydata$X1 = NULL
mydata = scale(mydata)
```

If you then want to perform `k-means` on the scaled data, I would just leave the row names as the identifiers to do any analysis. You can put them back whenever you want with `mydata$X1 = rownames(mydata)`.